# Checking PCNTL extension installed in PHP

Tags: php, pcntl

One of background scripts in my project uses PCNTL to fork. Also, I have a requirement checker script that should be run by user before script installation. Since pcntl can be accessed only in CGI mode, both `function_exists('pcntl_fork')` and `extension_loaded('pcntl')` return `FALSE` in Web mode, so my checker shows always requirement error, as it launched via browser, even if it is enabled. Is there any method to check `pcntl` support is enabled from web mode?

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has answered, I thought I should just point out that you can create a standalone PHP script that checks for the existence of pcntl, then run that script with PHP CLI using, for example, [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).